# Script if else statement not working automatically

Tags: javascript

I have written a script to add some CSS to my site.

This is the HTML of my site:

```
<li class="chbs-booking-extra-list-item-quantity-enable first" data-category_id="" data-vehicle_id="-1">
    <div class="chbs-column-1">
        <div class="booking-form-extra-options"><div id="handling_extra">
            <div class="handling-inner one">
                text
            </div>
            <div class="handling-inner two">
                text
            </div>
            <div class="handling-inner three current">
                text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chbs-column-3">
        <div class="chbs-button-radio">
            <a href="#" class="chbs-button chbs-button-style-2" data-value="10078">
                Yes
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="chbs-button chbs-button-style-2" data-value="0">
                No
            </a>
            <input type="hidden" name="chbs_booking_extra_value[10078]" value="-1">
            <span>*</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I want if the `current` class is present with the class `three`, then the first value of radio will show and hide the second one.

Similarly, if the `current` class is present with the class `one`, then the first value of radio will hide and show the second one.

I have used this script for that:

```
if (jQuery(".handling-inner.one").hasClass("current")) {
    jQuery(".chbs-booking-extra-list-item-quantity-enable.first .chbs-button:first-child").css("display","none");
    jQuery(".chbs-booking-extra-list-item-quantity-enable.first .chbs-button:nth-child(2)").css("display","block");
}
else if (jQuery(".handling-inner.two").hasClass("current")) {
    jQuery(".chbs-booking-extra-list-item-quantity-enable.first .chbs-button:first-child").css("display","block");
    jQuery(".chbs-booking-extra-list-item-quantity-enable.first .chbs-button:nth-child(2)").css("display","none");
}
else if (jQuery(".handling-inner.three").hasClass("current")) {
    jQuery(".chbs-booking-extra-list-item-quantity-enable.first .chbs-button:first-child").css("display","block");
    jQuery(".chbs-booking-extra-list-item-quantity-enable.first .chbs-button:nth-child(2)").css("display","none");
}
```

But it only works for the first time. But it is not changing if the current class is changed.

Can someone please let me know what is wrong in the script?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to call if else checking function after current class is changed as well.

Comment: The current class is set to change on .click function